# How to get the date-time pattern from a DateTimeFormatter object

Tags: jodatime

The usual methods used for getting the pattern in Joda for Short Date-Time by passing locale is like below:

```
String pattern = DateTimeFormat.patternForStyle("SS", formatLocale);
```

But still is there any possibility for **get the pattern(eg: yy-dd-mm H:mm) from a DateTimeformatter**?

```
DateTimeFormatter format;
```

Can i get/retrieve pattern from this format object once all the details(locale, zone, country) are set?

Comment: Could you please put the code into code tags? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look for a generic way to retrieve the format pattern for any arbitrarily constructed formatter, then the answer is: **No, not possible.**

Reason is that a formatter constructed via the builder pattern allows format details which cannot be covered by any pattern. Examples:

For the builder method [appendYearOfCentury(...)](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendYearOfCentury-int-int-) there is no pattern [equivalent](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html). Or the formatter exploits the option to include a [custom parser](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#append-org.joda.time.format.DateTimePrinter-org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParser-) which can never be covered by any pattern symbol. Similar considerations are valid for other time libraries including Java-8, too.